# SQL Server Merge Statement - Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error when executing this SQL script:

```
MERGE TridionCentres TridionCentres
USING (SELECT * FROM  #CentresToUpdate) NewInfo
ON (TridionCentres.[publication id] = NewInfo.[publication id] AND
    TridionCentres.centre_number = NewInfo.centre_number)
WHERE matched THEN 
  UPDATE 
    SET TridionCentres.centre = NewInfo.centre,
        TridionCentres.[date] = NewInfo.[date];
```

Error:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.*

I can't see where I've gone wrong!

Comment: the keyword is WHEN, not WHERE :) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @tr3 You should add your comment as an answer. (And probably posting the fixed query)

Comment: Why do so many people post their answer as a comment ?

Comment: @tr3 I suspect that your answer got deleted because, even though it identified the problem, it was mostly a link only answer. You can probably post it again, this thime adding the fixed query on your answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith It actually was a comment that was then posted as an answer and then got deleted

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right, but before I clearly saw the comment with a previous time stamp that the answer. (I mean, the comment said "13 mins ago" and the answer said "15 mins ago")

Comment: @Lamak - Maybe the live updates of times is a bit inconsistent (deleted now irrelevant previous comments)

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, the weird part is that when I saw this post, there was only the comment and couldn't see the deleted answer. After that, I saw the deleted answer and assumed that tr3 had posted his comment as an answer, not sure of what actually happened

Comment: @All Sorry, will try to post better answers next time :) Thank you guys for editing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword is WHEN, not WHERE :)

More about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), but a bit much to put into an answer.